# Windows Forms look different in Powershell and Powershell ISE. Why?

Tags: forms, powershell, powershell-ise

I have written a script which is basically a small wysiwyg signature generator for Outlook. We want our signatures to be in corporate colours, and semi-standardised - hence the requirement for this.

I did the development work in Powershell ISE and all looked good. However, when I run the script just using powershell (as the users will) it looks totally different:

[Powershell vs Powershell ISE http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1d6e6c5c6f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1d6e6c5c6f.png)

The top one was generated in ISE, and looks as I want it. The bottom one was run from powershell directly and seems to have visually regressed five years!

How can I get the script to look as snazzy in Powershell as it does in Powershell ISE?

Comment: What a neat idea! Please consider sharing the script on PoshCode.org (or elsewhere) if your employer is cool like that.

Comment: Your image URL doesn't start with `https://`. Please edit your question to upload the image in Imgur.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add the following line in your script before you show the form:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
```

Comment: I actually love you! Cheers Dude, this was sending me up the wall!

Comment: NP.  BTW if this answers your question, you might want to mark it as answered.  :-)

Comment: `+1` although it doesn't answer the "***..., Why?***", See also: [Why does the icon and buttons on the popup look different sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72245690/1701026)