# Why does my System Windows Form look different when the .ps1 file is run from a shortcut?

Tags: forms, powershell, winforms, monthcalendar

I'm using Windows.Forms.MonthCalendar from the System.Windows.Forms assembly.

When running the script from Powershell ISE, it looks like this:
[image]

But when running the script via a dekstop shortcut, it looks like this:
(Shortcut target: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Temp\Test.ps1")
[image]

If Powershell ISE is using a later version of Powershell, how can I use that version in my shortcut?

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358372/windows-forms-look-different-in-powershell-and-powershell-ise-why, although the images are no longer available in that question…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add the following before creating the form:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles();
```